How to disable Github Copilot "start typing to dismiss" in VS Code terminal?
Copilot shows a "...ask GitHub Copilot to do something. Start typing to dismiss." message each time a new terminal is opened. Can this message be disabled?

Try this:
"terminal.integrated.initialHint": false,


"github.copilot.editor.enableAutoCompletions": false,
